# Problema al intentar enviar email con Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

Error

```
PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46 - assumed 'INTL_IDNA_VARIANT_UTS46'

Filename: libraries/Email.php
```

Mi archivo

```
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->to('xd@gmail.com');
        $this->email->from('xd2@hotmail.com','xxxxx');
        $this->email->subject('Test Email (TEXT)');
        $this->email->message('Text email testing by CodeIgniter Email library.');
        $this->email->send();
```

Alguien sabe a que se debe el problema?
El error apunta a esta linea:

```
$this->email->send();
```

El mensaje llega correctamente, el problema es porque me marca eso?

Comment: Qué versión de PHP está utilizando?

Comment: Ya un bug reportado en https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-69780.html

Comment: El servidor me da:  _Versión de PHP: 5.6.30_

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo que pudiera estar faltando seria la configuración del email:

Ejemplo:

```
 function sendEmail(){

     $this->load->library('email');
     $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
     $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
     $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
     $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
     $config['smtp_user']    = 'usuariogmail@gmail.com';
     $config['smtp_pass']    = 'contraseñagmail';
     $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
     $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
     $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // o html
     $config['validation'] = TRUE; // para validar el correo electronico 

     $this->email->initialize($config);

     $this->email->from('usuariogmail@gmail.com', 'myname');
     $this->email->to('usuario@gmail.com'); 

     $this->email->subject('Email Test');
     $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

     $this->email->send();

    }
```

Nota importante las configuraciones también se pueden poner en un fichero externo email.php en ./application/config/.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
    $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'usuariogmail@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = 'contraseñagmail';
    $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // o html
    $config['validation'] = TRUE; // para validar el correo electronico 
>
```

Siempre sustituye usuario y contraseña de gmail por las reales de usted...

Answer (score 0):

Abre el archivo de `php.ini` en `Xamp` o `Appserver`

Descomenta la línea

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Busca la línea `[Date]` y agrega o cambia

```
date.timezone = America/Mexico_City
```

Reinicia `apache`.